# Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart' can be reused

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to crate a line chart using the Chart.js library, I was following an youtube tutorial everything worked fine from their end, but I was getting the error " Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart' can be reused. " in console of chrome. I named data as dota because there is another variable named data.

Html code:

```
<div class="chart">
        <canvas id="myChart">

        </canvas>

    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.1/chart.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Javascript code:

```
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");


            const labels = [
                "2002",
                "2003",
                "2004",
            ];
            const dota = {
                labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        dota: ['3', '1', '2'],
                        label: "OK",
                    },
                ],
            };
            const config = {
                type: 'line',
                data: dota,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                },

            };
            const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

I am trying to create a line chart, I get the axis values shown but the line (curve) is not showing.

Comment: Try replacing all occurrence of myChart to something else.

Comment: Also it is fine if you call your variable as dota. But i guess inside dataset the key should be data only

Comment: To explicitize what @CodeThing said: change `dota: ['3', '1', '2'],` to `data: ['3', '1', '2'],` - the other `dota` you may keep.